# Doubts about Lax's proof of change of variables

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Consider the following step of p. 499 from [Lax's proof of the change of variables theorem](http://www.math.nthu.edu.tw/~jyhhaur/teaching/advancedcalculusII2013spring/Lax.pdf):

**Lemma**

Let $\phi \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^2)$ and denote by $D\phi_j$ the gradient of the j-th component of $\phi$. Let $D= (\partial_{x_1}, \dots, \partial x_n )^T$.

Then

$$ \det((D,D\phi_2, \dots , D\phi_n )) = \sum_{2 \le k \le n} \det((D,D\phi_2, \dots, D\phi_n ))_k $$

Where the subscript k means that the differential operator D in the first column acts only on the k-th column.
Moreover each determinant in the sum is zero.

I mean, I wrote it down in dimension 3 but a rigorous proof is another thing!

Any suggestion?